# How can I get content type from an ActiveStorage attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I'm creating a view that features a video stored via ActiveStorage. Currently I'm displaying the video like this:

```
%video{ controls: true, preload:"metadata" }
    %source{ src: rails_blob_path(@video.source), type: "TODO: Content Type" }
```

I'd like to find a way to get the content type from the attachment. I've found that I can get to it by using `@video.source.attachment.blob.content_type`but that seems so clunky. Is there another simpler way to go about it that resembles `video.source.content_type`? Unfortunately using the `video_tag` helper is not a viable solution for me.

Comment: why don't you add a helper method on your model? `def content_type; source.attachment.blob.content_type; end` and then you do `@video.content_type`?

Comment: @arieljuod Before I do that, I want to be sure my helper method isn't just reinventing an existing method.

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a shorter solution: `@video.source_blob.content_type`.

I recommend you to look at the source code of ActiveStorage, there you can see all the available methods and possibilities that are not always well documented.

Answer (score 7):

You can access content type directly from the attachment , there is not need to call it in thet blob , just do : `@video.content_type`

```
class ActiveStorage::Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "active_storage_attachments"

  belongs_to :record, polymorphic: true, touch: true
  belongs_to :blob, class_name: "ActiveStorage::Blob"

  delegate_missing_to :blob #This line allow you to call all the blob methods from attachmen
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full answer including `@video.content_type`

Answer (score 1):

ActiveStorage uses Marcel to validate and get content types. An exhaustive list of everything is available here:

https://github.com/rails/marcel/blob/main/lib/marcel/tables.rb